# jQuery Adding Block of HTML works except drop down not showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I finally was able to get this working using other solutions I found on SO. The only issue I am running into is that it wont include the drop down. Basically what I am trying to do is create an invoice page where I can add line items and add in the details for the invoice.

Html is in bootstrap so you will see the col's added in this.

```js
var addDetail = '<div class="col-lg-12 col-detail"><div class="item-detail-bg"><div class="col-lg-5"><h4><strong>Item Details</strong></h4><div class="col-xs-12 no-margin"><select name="test2" class="select2" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="Add Item Detail"><option></option><optgroup label="Retail"><option value="1">Sequin Top - fh18997</option><option value="2">Booty Shorts - 57638</option><option value="3">Sweat Band - 77638</option><option value="4">Another Retail - 99878</option><option value="5">Item for Retail - 33749</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Tuition"><option value="1">Tuition</option></optgroup></select><br /><textarea class="form-control" id="field-ta" placeholder="Item Description"></textarea></div></div><div class="col-lg-1"><h4><strong>Quantity</strong></h4><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="1.00"></div><div class="col-lg-1"><h4><strong>Amount</strong></h4><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-lg-1"><h4><strong>Discount</strong></h4><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="entypo-down-open"></i></button><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown"><li><a href="#">%</a></li><li><a href="#">$</a></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="col-lg-1"><h4><strong>Tax</strong></h4><select class="form-control"><option>None</option><option>CA 8.0%</option><option>+New Tax</option></select></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-right"><h3><strong>Item Total</strong></h3><h3 class="no-margin">$250.98</h3></div><div class="clearfix item-margin"></div></div>';

$("#add").click(function () {

 $('.add-line-item').append(addDetail);

});

$("#reset").click(function () {
  location.reload();
});

// <div class="col-lg-12 col-detail">
// <div class="item-detail-bg">
//  <div class="col-lg-5">
//  <h4><strong>Item Details</strong></h4>
//   <div class="col-xs-12 no-margin">
//    <select name="test2" class="select2" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder="Add Item Detail">
//     <option></option>
//     <optgroup label="Retail">
//      <option value="1">Sequin Top - fh18997</option>
//      <option value="2">Booty Shorts - 57638</option>
//      <option value="3">Sweat Band - 77638</option>
//      <option value="4">Another Retail - 99878</option>
//      <option value="5">Item for Retail - 33749</option>
//     </optgroup>
//     <optgroup label="Tuition">
//      <option value="1">Tuition</option>
//     </optgroup>
//    </select>
//    <br />
//    <textarea class="form-control" id="field-ta" placeholder="Item Description"></textarea>
//   </div>
//  </div>
//   <div class="col-lg-1">
//    <h4><strong>Quantity</strong></h4>
//     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="1.00">
//    </div>
//   <div class="col-lg-1">
//    <h4><strong>Amount</strong></h4>
//    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="">
//   </div>
//   <div class="col-lg-1">
//    <h4><strong>Discount</strong></h4>
//    <div class="input-group">
//     <input type="text" class="form-control">
    
//     <div class="input-group-btn">     
//      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
//       <i class="entypo-down-open"></i>
//      </button>
     
//      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown">
//       <li><a href="#">%</a></li>
//       <li><a href="#">$</a></li>
//      </ul>
//     </div>
//    </div>
//   </div>
//   <div class="col-lg-1">
//    <h4><strong>Tax</strong></h4>
//    <select class="form-control">
//     <option>None</option>
//     <option>CA 8.0%</option>
//     <option>+New Tax</option>
//    </select>
//   </div>
//   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-right">
//    <h3><strong>Item Total</strong></h3>
//    <h3 class="no-margin">$250.98</h3>
//   </div>

//    <div class="clearfix item-margin"></div>
// </div>
// </div>
```

```html
<div class="add-line-item"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-icon icon-left" id="add">Add Item<i class="entypo-plus"></i></button>
```

I also included a commented version of the addDetail variable that has all of the line breaks.

Comment: `"$ is not defined"` Did you add jQuery to your snippet?

Comment: Does changing $('.add-line-item').append(addDetail); to $('.add-line-item').append($(addDetail)); address your issue?

Comment: @TrentStewart No that yields the same result. Everything shows but the drop down.

Comment: Here is an image of what my current code is giving me. Note the missing drop down. http://imgur.com/yDBDttV

Comment: So it is adding everything except the drop down? Have you tried using dom inspector to see if it is actually there? If not try removing the optgroup tags maybe this is confusing jquery.

Comment: Ya the inspector shows it there, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Ok so I figured out that it was the drop down from my theme. I used the standard bootstrap dropdown and it is working correctly now. Very strange. Anyone have any ideas what jQuery is not liking?